# comparacion de valores repetidos jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

de que manera podria hacer una comparacion mediante la cual detecte si ya tengo un elemento en un array?

Tengo un array ($producto = []) que va guardando el id de un select, pero necesito que si ese id se repita se muestre un alert...

estoy probando con esta funcion:

```
  function agregar(){
        //e.preventDefault();
         material_id = $('#amaterial_id').val();
         material = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").text();
         cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
         seriado = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").data('seriado');
         $('#seriados').val(seriado);

        if (material_id!="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0 ){
            var producto =[material_id];
             if(material_id == $('.test').val()){

                    if (seriado == 0) {
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected testing" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="cargarSeries('+cont+');">Cargar Series</button></td><td><input type="hidden" class="test" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                    } else {
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected testing"  id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" ">No Seriable</button></td><td><input type="hidden" class="test" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                    }
                    $('#detalles').append(fila);

                }else{
                    alert('repetido');
                } 
                cont++;
                //total++;
                $('#guardar').show();
                limpiarControles();
                //evaluar();
                //$('#detalles').append(fila);
            }else{
                alert("Revise que se hallan seleccionado materiales");
                $('#guardar').hide();
            }
    }
```

pero no cumple la condicion por mas que cambie de operador...

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actualización

De acuerdo a los requerimientos que solicitaste, se adaptó el nuevo `código` al que tienes.
Hay algunos detalles en los cuales debes poner atención.
Por ejemplo, el `array` **ids** se tiene que declarar fuera de la `función` **agregar()**, ya que si lo declaras dentro, no funcionará.
Se agregó una `variable booleana` llamada **repetido** que cambiará a `true` cuando encuentre un producto ya seleccionado, y esa variable será evaluada también en el primer `if`.

Cuando cumpla las condiciones de ese `if`, se irá llenando el `array` **ids** con los `identificadores` que el `select` obtenga, y si se vuelve a seleccionar un producto ya seleccionado, lanzará el `alert` que dice *"No se han seleccionado materiales o el material ya está agregado"*, indicando que ya **no** se puede volver a seleccionar ese producto.

```
var ids = [];

function agregar(){

    var repetido = false;
    var material_id = parseInt( $('#amaterial_id').val() );
    material = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").text();
    cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
    seriado = $("#amaterial_id option:selected").data('seriado');
    $('#seriados').val(seriado);



    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){

        if(ids[i] == material_id){ 
            repetido = true;
        }           
    }

        
    if( material_id != "" && cantidad != "" && cantidad > 0  && !repetido){

        ids.push(material_id);

        if(material_id == $('.test').val()){

                if (seriado == 0) {
                var fila = '<tr class="selected testing" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="cargarSeries('+cont+');">Cargar Series</button></td><td><input type="hidden" class="test" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                } else {
                var fila = '<tr class="selected testing"  id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled" ">No Seriable</button></td><td><input type="hidden" class="test" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                }
                $('#detalles').append(fila);

            }else{
                alert('repetido');
            } 
            cont++;
            //total++;
            $('#guardar').show();
            limpiarControles();
            //evaluar();
            //$('#detalles').append(fila);

    }else{
        alert("No se han seleccionado materiales o el material ya está agregado");
        $('#guardar').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: hola, funciona, el tema es que el valor a buscar debe ser el que venga del select, se decir el select lo presiono y me trae el id de un producto, si vuelvo a presionar el producto desde el select no deberia dejarme seguir

Comment: @NicolasAlmonacid ok, actualiza tu pregunta y adjunta el código de tu select donde se muestre donde obtiene el id... y pon una explicación más clara, ya que no me quedó claro esto: "si vuelvo a presionar el producto desde el select no deberia dejarme seguir".  Para poder actualizar mi respuesta de acuerdo a lo que buscas. Esta respuesta la hice de acuerdo al código que muestras.

Comment: ok, añadi el codigo de la funcion, con ese if que tengo se cumple la condicional, pero solo una vez, ya cuando selecciono otro producto deja de funciar

Comment: con el segundo if...en cuanto a "si vuelvo a presionar el producto desde el select no deberia dejarme seguir" lo que quise decir es que solamente podria seleccionar una vez el producto desde el select, si yo volviera a seleccionar el mismo producto es donde debo alertar que ya lo tengo en la lista

Comment: @NicolasAlmonacid ya actualicé mi respuesta, pruébalo, y si te funciona, marca como respuesta correcta, si no, me lo haces saber.

Comment: funciono perfecto, solo quite un if que estaba demas